# Query for counting number of employees in district and region

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I am working on a dashboard on HighCharts Column chart to represent the number of employees in a Region and when I click the column of that Region, it should drill down and show the number of employees in all the districts of that Region. The employee table is connected to District table and District table is connected to Region table.

[image]

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT ad.DISTRICT_NAME, COUNT(me.district_id), r.REGION_NAME, COUNT(me.district_id) 
FROM `master_employee` me 
INNER JOIN app_district ad ON me.`district_id` = ad.`DISTRICT_UID`
INNER JOIN region r ON ad.REGION_UID = r.REGION_UID 
GROUP BY me.district_id, ad.REGION_UID
```

But it shows number of employees in a district. How can I group them and get the number of employees in a Region ?

**Fiddle**

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec468c/1

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: so I reformatted your code @mehmoodmemon -- what do you notice **about the last line**??

Comment: I have added the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP to provide an additional row for each Region where the District Name would be NULL and the count would be the roll-up of the district level count for that region?

This SQL should get you pointed in the right direction with my train of thought. I played with your Fiddle, it seemed to approximate what you were asking:

```
SELECT r.Region_Name
     , ad.District_Name
     , Count(me.employee_id)
  FROM `master_employee` me 
 INNER JOIN app_district ad 
         ON me.`district_id` = ad.`DISTRICT_UID`
 INNER JOIN region r 
         ON ad.REGION_UID = r.REGION_UID 
 GROUP BY ad.REGION_UID, ad.District_Name WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: WOW didn't knew about ROLLUP. Thanks !!

Comment: But what about the last row in the result ? It shows the region name and in counts all records. How can we stop that ?

Comment: I saw that, and didn't know if that was a SQL Fiddle behavior or a MySQL behavior. I don't have an instance of MySQL handy to test.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a group by region

```
 SELECT  r.REGION_NAME, COUNT(*) as number_of_employee
 FROM `master_employee` me 
 INNER JOIN app_district ad ON me.`district_id` = ad.`DISTRICT_UID` 
 INNER JOIN region r ON ad.REGION_UID = r.REGION_UID 
 GROUP BY  ad.REGION_UID
```

Comment: Thanks.
But is there any possibility to get both results in same query. I mean number of employees in region and number of employees in district ?

Comment: I think not in sql (on not in a simple way) because the level of aggregation is different .. the district level is more detailed of the region level. Otherwise You cant obtain both the result using a server side language.